# How to change Ionic Back button dynamically in Ionic 5

Tags: ionic-framework, button, text, back

I'd like to change back button dynamically in app having localization feature in Ionic 5.
Of course, I can do it **config.set** function in Ionic 3 but it is deprecated in Ionic 5.
I want the same function I can use that in a page like profile setting page.

Comment: Do you mean the back text as the answer below or the icon that is displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my current solution.
`<ion-back-button [text]="backButtonText"></ion-back-button>`

This works well in the page but I don't like to add the same code `[text]="backButtonText"` in other pages too.